# Save a birthDate via qraphql in postgres

Tags: postgresql, date, graphql, knex.js

I would like to save a birthdate from an (react) input (type = 'date'), send it via GraphQL to node backend and persist it in postgres in a date format.

1. Input in HTML: `09.07.2000`
2. In GraphQL resolver: `2000-07-09T00:00:00.000Z`
3. Date format in Postgres (original output in console): `09.07.2000`

Well, that's what i expected. But now, if i request the same field:

1. Date format in Postgres (original output in console): `09.07.2000`
2. Graphql response: `08.07.2000`
3. HTML Input: `08.07.2000`

If I change the scalar in graphQl schema to `String`, the following string returns: `Fri Jul 09 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

### Code

#### schema

```
scalar Date

type Child {
  ...
  birthDate: Date
  ...
}
```

#### resolvers

```
const { GraphQLDate } = require('graphql-iso-date')
...
Date: GraphQLDate,
```

### Problem

It looks like there is a problem in converting the date format from different timezones. If there is no timezone the scalar resolver guess a timezone. But this is a birthdate, it hast to be the same date on every timezone. How can I fix this? Do I have to use a string instead of date in prostgres?

Thanks for any support  I'm really lost

**UPDATE**
It looks like knex.js is the problem.
A normal SQL query responds the expected date. But a query with knex.js response a datetime.